# How to make one JPA repository Transactional but another not?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have method where I'm trying to change some entity, also in this method I want to save transaction information.
When any exception occurred I want to roll back saving entity but still want to save transaction.
So how to make one repository for entity transactional but repository for transactions not?

There code from repository

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=NotEnoughAmountInAccountException.class)
<T extends Transaction> T save(T transaction);
```

but it doesn't help.
Saving transaction placed in final block.

**UPDATE**

I solved it by using AOP. I create Transaction object in aspect advice and save it here, out of JPA transaction.

Comment: Please ask a question, show us exceptions trace...

Comment: I've added question. There is no stack trace, just transaction is also not saved due to roll back.

Comment: What you might want to do is leave repository classes as they are, and have service methods with different transactional behaviours so that when you call your method, it will call other service methods with different transactional behavior( for ex. Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). This way you can save "transaction" and in the case of any unchecked exception or with your `NotEnoughAmountInAccountException` outer transaction may be rolled back but inner transaction with new behavior will still be committed.

Comment: It doesn't work. As I understand Spring creates proxy methods only for public methods, so @Transactional on private method doesn't work. I don't want to make it public because someone can call it without saving transaction.

Comment: can you please post what you did to solve the problem as an answer with some code ? and accept your answer yourself ... it may help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using AOP. I create Transaction object in aspect advice and save it here, out of JPA transaction.

It's @Transactional method

```
@SaveTransaction
@Transactional
public synchronized Transaction move(@NonNull String accountName, @NonNull String destinationName, @NonNull BigDecimal amount, String comment) {
    checkAmountIsPositive(amount);

    Account donor = getAccount(accountName);
    Account acceptor = getAccount(destinationName);

    if (!isEnoughAmount(accountName, amount)) throw new NotEnoughAmountInAccountException();

    BigDecimal newDonorAmount = donor.getAmount().add(amount.negate());
    BigDecimal newAcceptorAmount = acceptor.getAmount().add(amount);

    donor.setAmount(newDonorAmount);
    acceptor.setAmount(newAcceptorAmount);

    accountRepository.save(donor);
    accountRepository.save(acceptor);

    return null;
}
```

And it's aspect advice

```
@Around("@annotation(com.softjourn.coin.server.aop.annotations.SaveTransaction)")
public Transaction saveTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Transaction transaction = prepareTransaction(joinPoint);
    try {
        joinPoint.proceed();
        transaction.setStatus(TransactionStatus.SUCCESS);
        return transaction;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        transaction.setStatus(TransactionStatus.FAILED);
        transaction.setError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw e;
    } finally {
        transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }
}
```

Also it's important to make order of this advice higher than order of @Transactional so this advice will be over transaction. 
Set @Order(100) on aspect class.
By default it's order is smaller so it's under transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a new `@Transactional`

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
<T extends Transaction> T save(T transaction);
```

This will save your `transaction` element even if the other `@Transactional` gets rolled back

Comment: maybe it is because you're overriding the default `save` from spring-data, which is `@Transactional` ... try doing it in a custom method, something like  a method named `saveTransaction(T transaction)`... it should work (of course, you will have to implement that custom method )

Comment: It also doesn't work. As I understand Spring creates proxy methods only for public methods, so @Transactional on private method doesn't work. I don't want to make it public because someone can call it without saving transaction.

Comment: oh ok, it is a private method ... then `@Transactional` won't work ... you can simply delete that annotation on private methods ... and then,  i have no other solution for you ...  BTW : spring creates proxies for public methods, yes, but if you want to use a `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` in any of the methods, it shouldn't be in the same class as the caller, that new propagation level will be ignored as well